# Python - Random.sample from a range with excluded values (array)

Tags: python, random

I am currently using the random.sample function to extract individuals from a population.

ex:

n = range(1,1501)

result = random.sample(n, 500)
print(result)

in this example I draw 500 persons among 1500. So far, so good..

Now, I want to go further and launch a search with a list of exclude people.

exclude = [122,506,1100,56,76,1301]

So I want to get a list of people (1494 persons) while excluding this array (exclude)

I must confess that I am stuck on this question. Do you have an idea ?
thank you in advance!

I am learning Python language. I do a lot of exercise to train. Nevertheless I block ue on this one.

Comment: Why don't you: If the random draw is one of the excluded values, draw again?

Comment: Could you exclude before you sample ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
exclude = {122, 506, 1100, 56, 76, 1301}
result = random.sample([k for k in range(1, 1501) if k not in exclude], 500)

# check
assert set(result).isdisjoint(exclude)
```

Marginally faster (but a bit more convoluted for my taste):

```py
result = random.sample(list(set(range(1, 1501)).difference(exclude)), 500)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

exclude = {1, 6}

result = random.sample(list(set(range(1, 21)).difference(exclude)), 18)

print(result)
```

Thank you for your reply. It works perfectly with this example!